# How to add contents to an xml file from js

Tags: javascript, html, xml, node.js

When i do this

```
   var obj = {item:{title: params.title,description: text, link: req.headers['origin']+"/blog/blog-description/"+params.blog_id,guid:req.headers['origin']+"/blog/blog-description/"+params.blog_id}};
```

i got,

```
     <item>
      <title>errerewr</title>
        <description>erewrewrewrewrw</description>
          <link>
            http://localhost:4220/blog//ererewrewrqwrwe
          </link>
           <guid>
            http://localhost:4220/blog/ererewrewrqwrwe
           </guid>
     </item>
```

but i want to add enclosure like below,

```
 <enclosure url="http://example.com/file.mp3" length="123456789" type="audio/mpeg" />
```

so far i had done for adding cotents in between tags but now for enclouse i had to add contents in the tag here i got strucked.Can anyone suggest help.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where do you want to add the enclosure? What did you try so far?

Comment: Hi Amiram,hoe to append data to xml such that it looks like this in xml <enclosure url="http://example.com/file.mp3" length="123456789" type="audio/mpeg" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most js-2-xml conversion utils you should use `'@'` or `'$'` for adding attributes, while convertng js object to xml.

**Example:**

```
 var obj = {
    item:{
        title: params.title,
        description: text,
        link: req.headers['origin']+"/blog/blog-description/"+params.blog_id,guid:req.headers['origin']+"/blog/blog-description/"+params.blog_id,
        enclosure: {
                '@' : {
                    url: params.url, //you need to replace it aacording to your app logic of course
                    length: params.length,
                    type: params.type
                }
            }
    }
};
```

Comment: but i am getting like this       <enclosure>
    <@>
      <url>http://localhost:4000/uploads/</url>
    </@>
  </enclosure>

Comment: enclosure: {
                                 '@' : {
                                url: req.headers['origin'] + "/uploads/" + params.image
                            }
                        },

Comment: It all depends on how you are converting the `obj` into xml. Are you using some nodejs package for conversion?

Comment: sorry i am using    var xml2js = require('xml2js');     
                    var builder = new xml2js.Builder();
                    var xml = builder.buildObject(obj);

Comment: for xml2js, according to it's docs you must use `'$' : {url: req.headers['origin'] + "/uploads/" + params.image } }` i'll update the answer

Comment: Thank you very much SergeyK and where did u search for that?

Comment: Your can find almost any nodejs package documentation on https://www.npmjs.com for example https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js for xml2js, there are github links there too.